# Django Contact form: TypeError: "to" argument must be a list or tuple

Tags: django, forms, view

I am trying to get my email contact form to work on my Django website.
I am getting an error in my browser as follows:

> Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:  "to" argument must be a
>   list or tuple Exception
>   Location: /home/Gassymule/Skeletonv3.1/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py
>   in **init**, line 264

It specifically highlights

```
try:
     send_mail(name, company, phone, subject, message, from_email, ['kkeeper.ch@gmail.com'])
```

from my views.py but I am not entirely sure what it needs me to fix. The Tutorial website that I took this from used this exact format.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from website.forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            try:
                send_mail(name, company, phone, subject, message, from_email, ['kkeeper.ch@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})


def thanks(request):
    return HttpResponse('Thank you for your message.')
```

Here is the relevant code from my contact form template.

**email.html**

```
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <ul class="contactList">
                    <li id="name" class="contact">{{ form.name }}</li>
                    <li id="company" class="contact">{{ form.company }}</li>
                    <li id="email" class="contact">{{ form.from_email }}</li>
                    <li id="phone" class="contact">{{ form.phone }}</li>
                    <li id="subject" class="contact">{{ form.subject }}</li>
                    <li id="message" class="contact">{{ form.message }}</li>
                </ul>
                <input id=submitb type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here is my forms.py

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False,)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 43, 'rows': 8}))
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    company = forms.CharField(required=False)



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['from_email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Email'
        self.fields['subject'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Subject'
        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Message'
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Name'
        self.fields['phone'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Phone'
        self.fields['company'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Company'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `send_mail` you need to pass arguments like this.

```
(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

Where `recipient_list` is a list or tuple of email_addresses to send mail to.

You are passing, other arguments: just do this

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['kkeeper.ch@gmail.com'])
```

and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the `send_email` method is

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail

Remove first three arguments: `name, company, phone` from your code.